# Built-in database limits for Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, database

When I install Sharepoint Foundation 2013 as a stand alone installation, it uses a 'built-in' database. What is the maximum database size here?

Comment: I answered a similar question.

It might help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97854/limits-of-running-of-sql-express-for-sharepoint-2013/97918#97918

Answer (score 1):

I believe in that case it uses SQL Server Express, for which the limit is presently [10 GB per database.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Comment: Limitations are listed in the following link for SQL Express 2012:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx Regards, Ralph Boccalini