# Would SQL express result in sharepoint response flakiness?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-express

I get that [Limits of Running of SQL express for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97854/limits-of-running-of-sql-express-for-sharepoint-2013) makes you limited in some ways.

But what does that mean in terms of sharepoint usage? If using Sql express would that explain random 500 errors from sharepoint?

What will be the actual result for users? I want to save that money if I can of course.

Answer (score 0):

As you know limitation of CPU and Memory usage by SQL express edition may cause you 500 errors. Due to memory limitation on express edition (1Gb) then too many requests on the SQL can cause the issue...you may get 500 errors or server too busy or the page cannot display.

It is not recommended use the SQL express in your production. You can read the SQL server 2012 express edition limitation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: Even in a development / test environment, random 500 errors makes it really hard to use.

Comment: It's depend what u doing? May be problem with Sharepoint servers rather sql...

Comment: we are running a test that uses the sharepoint api to go through some files and do some processing. if any of the files doesn't appear, it will fail the test. sometimes 2 out of say 70 files will error when requesting them thus the failure.